# Working with complex functions and complex conjugation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I have a complex function and I want to take a list of derivatives of it. My code reads as follows:

```
$Assumptions[w>0] 
f[r, t] = Exp[-I wt] (It Exp[-I wr]/r + R Exp[I w r]/r)
ComplexExpand[Conjugate[f[r, t]]]
```

In my function, I want the coefficients `It` and `R` to be complex numbers.
However, this gives me the following output:

```
(R Cos[r w] Cos[wt])/r + (It Cos[wr] Cos[wt])/r + (R Sin[r w] Sin[wt])/r - (It Sin[wr] Sin[wt])/r + I (-((R Cos[wt] Sin[r w])/r) + (It Cos[wt] Sin[wr])/r + (R Cos[r w] Sin[wt])/r + (It Cos[wr] Sin[wt])/r
```

This treats `It` and `R` as real numbers and it expands the exponentials using Euler's identity. How do I get the conjugate of the functions in a simpler form, and taking `It` and `R` as complex.

Comment: REad the manual about "ComplexExpand" and you will see that you need to indicate which variables are complex.

Comment: That still returns everything in terms of `Sin` and `Cos` even though the input is in terms of exponentials. The complex numbers themselves are also expressed as `Re[]` and `Im[]`. Is there some kind of `z` `z^*` style notation available?

Comment: Look at "TrigToExp"

Comment: Hard to tell if you mean `wr` or `w*r` in your code since you have it both ways.  It puts what you mean by`wt` in doubt also.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $Assumptions[w > 0]
f[r, t] = Exp[-I w t] (It Exp[-I w r]/r + R Exp[I w r]/r)
ce = ComplexExpand[Conjugate[f[r, t]], {It, R}, 
TargetFunctions -> Conjugate] // Simplify
ce // TraditionalForm
ce // TrigToExp
ce // TrigToExp // TraditionalForm
```